# Is this SWORD zero-extension example in the Irvine book really correct?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, twos-complement, irvine32

I'm very much a beginner and have been reading Assembly Language for x86 by Irvine. I am in the section on signed integer division and came across an example that really confuses me.

It is meant to be an example of what happens when you do not sign extend. Here is the line of code:

```
.data

 wordval SWORD -101      ;009Bh

.code

  mov DX, 0
  mov ax, wordVal         ; DX:AX = 0000009Bh (+155)
  mov bx, 2               ; BX is the divisor
  idiv bx                 ; divide DX:AX by BX (signed operation)
```

It then says that because ax really equals +155 the quotient produced is +77 instead of the expected result.

**Why is `-101` represented in the variable wordVal as 009B instead of FF9B in the second line of code?**

Here is my logic: 101 decimal is 65h. A SWORD is 16 bits so the two's complement should be 0FF9Bh. Then DX is set to 0 and DX:AX would be equal to 0000FF9Bh so if there is no sign extension the number would be interpreted as 65435 decimal.

---

I would have expected the code to read as follows:

```
.data

 wordval SWORD -101        ;FF9Bh

.code

 mov DX, 0
 mov ax, wordVal           ; DX:AX = 0000FF9Bh (+65435)
 mov bx, 2                 ; BX is the divisor
 idiv bx                   ; divide DX:AX by BX (signed operation)
```

with a quotient of 32717.

(Or with the normal `cwd` as setup for 16-bit `idiv`, it would actually calculate `-101 / 2` = `-50` remainder `-1`.  Or with an arithmetic right shift to divide by 2 efficiently, `AX = -51` with CF=1.)

**Is this a mistake in the the book or am I missing something?**

Comment: You're right, and Irvine was sloppy. If you continue reading, you will see that he then continues working with `byteVal SBYTE -101`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. This was driving me absolutely mad and my TA wasn't able to understand why I was confused.

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't get a TA to understand; you explained it pretty clearly and correctly in your question.  I only tweaked the formatting a bit, not the logic.  And yes to an experienced reader that's obviously the wrong bit-pattern for SWORD -101.  It's negative (so the high bit must be set) and small so the high byte has to be FF.  00 is very obviously wrong.  I guess the book meant to do `mov al, byteVal`, `mov ah, 0`, and `idiv bl`